# CSS gaps between image links for no reason

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

I've been trying to get this horizontal navigation sorted for the past few hours now and nothing is working. I've tried reset.css stylesheets, *{padding: 0; margin: 0) etc. and I still have gaps inbetween my image links.

You see, the navigation is made up of an unordered list of image links displayed inline, but there are gaps in between each image, left, right, top and bottom and I can't see why. It's the same in all browsers.

Here is a link to the page, and so source: [Beansheaf Temporary](http://pentathlongb-yorkshire.co.uk/tomsmith/Beansheaf/index2.html)

Link to css: http://pentathlongb-yorkshire.co.uk/tomsmith/Beansheaf/styles/fund2.css

The rest of the site is obviously still not done, it's just the navigation I'm worried about right now.

Comment: Hnh, small world; I've eaten there. =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To avoid floating the navigation `li`s, you've got -at least- two options to remove the spaces between inline elements.

```
<ul> 
  <li><a href="#"><img src="../hotel.jpg" /></a></li 
  ><li><a href="#"><img src="../foodDrink.jpg" /></a></li
  ><li><a href="#"><img src="../meetingsConferences.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Note that the closing `</li>` tag is closed on the subsequent line (except for the last one), which is valid and maintains readability (for me, at least).

The other option is slightly messier

```
<ul> 
  <li><a href="#"><img src="../hotel.jpg" /></a></li><!-- 
  --><li><a href="#"><img src="../foodDrink.jpg" /></a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="#"><img src="../meetingsConferences.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

And just uses html comments `<!-- ... -->` to comment-out the spaces that would otherwise be collapsed into a single space.

I do wish there was some way of specifying (for example):

```
ul li img {whitespace: none-between; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I used the commenting method so that float didn't mess anything up with the CSS.

Comment: @Infiniti Fizz: you're absolutely welcome, thanks for the up-vote. Also, the next time I go there for a meal I get to say I helped with the website. Even if the bar-staff won't care in the slightest =)

Comment: I had a similar problem, only i didn't have each image link as a new list item.   I ended up condensing them all onto a single line, I never though about putting the comment in.  Thanks. That will help

Answer (score 6):

Another approach, avoiding floats, is to set the font-size on the container to 0, and then re-set it back up for the LIs, like this:

```
#mainNav
{    font-size: 0}

#mainNav li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1em
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. (Sorry I've copied and pasted this for everyone but you all had the same answer :) )

Answer (score 3):

the gap below images links is due to the image being aligned with base text line by default, you can solve it simply declaring

```
li img {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

magic!

Comment: Perfect!!! This is exactly what's needed on moving on from XHTML to HTML5, all other ways do not work - spend half of my day to figure out why, and your hint was the only helpful one! UP!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing all spaces and line-breaks between the `li` elements.

Because you are displaying them inline, spaces in the HTML will act as if they were a space in inline text and cause a gap to be left when rendering.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. (Sorry I've copied and pasted this for everyone but you all had the same answer :) )

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
#mainNav li { 
  float:left;
}
```

to your CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. (Sorry I've copied and pasted this for everyone but you all had the same answer :) )

Answer (score 1):

It is because a new line in an HTML document will be interpreted as a space in the printed content. Since all of your 'li' elements are on new lines, it is adding a space between each of them. Make sure you display them as block elements and float them to the left so they run evenly together.

Answer (score 0):

You can float the list elements, then the white space doesn't interfer:

```
#mainNav li
{
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. (Sorry I've copied and pasted this for everyone but you all had the same answer :) )

Answer (score 0):

I use the line-height attribute on the li tag to fix this.

```
ul li { line-height:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution to this comes from http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/centered.html. And quoting:

> All we need to do is enclose the ul tag in an outer container that has a width of 100% and overflow set to hidden.
>
> The `<ul>` tag is then styled with a relative position and floated left with a left position of 50%.
>
> Finally the `<li>` tag is also styled with a relative position, floated left but this time with a right position of 50%.
>
> ...and that as they say is all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using xslt to show these element, you should make the following:

```
<xsl:template match=".//text()">  
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
</xsl:template>
```